# Is there a way to use Spring & REST with plain HTML pages instead of using jsp's?

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to find a way to configure spring MVC with REST in order to work with plain html pages. The reason I am wanting to do it this way is because I want to create an android or ios application using phone gap along with the html and javascript.

This will help me do less maintenance and programming to support both the browser and mobile applications. So far, I have started with a basic sample project created from eclipse's spring mvc template. It works good if the view is in a jsp format, however, if I change the view to .html and change the suffix to html as well I get page not found.

My second question, from all the examples I have seen, they all use .jsp files only. Can it be replaced by xhtml as in jsf or not?

### Sample code tested

```
/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/wb")
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */

        @RequestMapping("/create/")
        public String home(Device device, Model model) {
            if (device == null) {
                logger.info("no device detected");
            } else if (device.isNormal()) {
                logger.info("Device is normal");
            } else if (device.isMobile()) {
                logger.info("Device is mobile");
            } else if (device.isTablet()) {
                logger.info("Device is tablet");
            }
            return "home";
        }
}
```

Beans configuration

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven>
        <argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver" />
        </argument-resolvers>
    </annotation-driven>

        <!-- Use the DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor OR the DeviceResolverRequestFilter in the web.xml -->
    <interceptors>
        <!-- On pre-handle, resolve the device that originated the web request -->
       <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor" />
    </interceptors>
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.veera.myapp" />



</beans:beans>
```

Log when using .html

```
INFO : com.veera.myapp.HomeController - Device is normal
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/views/home.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

If I use .jsp instead .html, it works. [image]

Comment: JSP renders HTML. Are you saying you want to serve static resources?

Comment: Well not exactly static, I want to use jquery/ajax etc to retrieve any data.

Comment: I mean is the data you are retrieving static (same for every user) or dynamic?

Comment: data will be different for different user

Comment: What's the problem with JSPs then? You can use a Template Engine like thymeleaf if you really don't want to work with JSP, but I don't see the point.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? If you have created proper REST services those should produce JSON/XML or whatever you like. You can then use whatever technology you like to render a view. Be it HTML with JavaScript or a native iOS or Android application. Your REST application should only produce resources (JSON/XML/...) which can be interpreted by the technology used).

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes I tried myself, I was trying to redirect the page to an html which was not working.

Comment: @M.Deinum Just updated my answer with I had tried earlier.

Comment: I don't get it... You mention REST but the only thing you do is serve a static page?! Next to that the InternalResourceViewResolver expects a dynamic page (as it does some preparation for that). A thing that might work is adding the `<default-servlet-handler />` element into your configuration.